# Употребление "в том числе"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сказал сегодня так:

> Он сам всех в том числе и с этим праздником поздравил.

Имел в виду день памяти Романа Сладкопевца, и всем понятно, что другой праздник, с которым он поздравил — Покров.

Если я явно это подразумеваю, всё равно такая фраза будет неудачной и надо переформулировать следующим образом?

> Он сам всех поздравил с праздниками, в том числе и с этим.

Или мой вариант тоже допустим? Alex_ander, если выскажетесь по этому поводу, буду благодарен. Но прошу вас только обратить внимание на то, что в числе чего этот праздник должно быть понятно тому, кому я писал.

Comment: Ещё возник вопрос: в последнем абзаце я не обособил "в числе чего этот праздник", правильно это или нет?

Comment: Поминание-то — не красный день календаря.

Comment: Зато именинники славные, именно сладкопевцы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я убежден в *недопустимости* исходного варианта и в *безупречности* исправленного. После "всех, в том числе" должно было бы последовать что-то вроде "Васю с Петей" (кого именно в числе "всех"). Предложенный же в другом ответе вариант ничем не лучше; по поводу подобной фразеологии с присоединительным предлогом "в том числе" (в начале, в конце законченной фразы или в случайном её месте, как это бывает в перепалке посетителей агрессивных ток-шоу) я ранее приводил такой аргумент: попробуйте найти такое в русской классике, хотя бы в речи какого-нибудь косноязычного персонажа!

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Значит, "в том числе" может быть только присоединительным оборотом.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, кому вопрос адресован, но полагаю, что не одному Alex_ander'у.

На мой взгляд, в первом варианте действительно стилистическая ошибка, не то чтобы грубая, но  шершавящая язык. Наподобие бессмертного *"не только лишь всех"* от достославного киевского мэра.

Ваше исправление вполне возможно, и, пожалуй, это лучший выход. Но, справедливости ради, простая перестановка слов:

***"Он сам всех поздравил в том числе и с этим праздником"*** тоже вполне возможна.

Так что, судя по всему, вы не тут ошибку править решили.

> Не очень понимаю, почему так плохо: я хотел расставить именно таким
> образом и вроде в русском языке порядок слов довольно свободный и это
> позволяет

Порядок слов свободный настолько, насколько это не нарушает понимания. Предлоги же вы не будете ставить после существительного? И вообще служебные части речи (частицы, предлоги, союзы) обычно привязаны к знаменательным словам и/или имеют четкое место в предложении. Сочетание "в том числе" является составным союзом, отрывать его от знаменательного слова не рекомендуется.

Невыполнение такой рекомендации приводит к двусмысленности. Как я уже писал выше, ваше "он сам всех в том числе и с этим праздником поздравил" в силу оторванности союза от знаменательных слов допускает весьма вольные трактовки.

*Поздравил отдельных граждан: Петю, Машу, товарища Имярекова, в том числе всех.

Сделал несколько вещей: выпил рюмку, сходил в театр, выпорол сына... ну и с праздником поздравил.*
ну и т.д. И только где-то в конце этого списка абсурдов - требующееся вам значение.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, вопрос, конечно, не только Александру. Значит, вы считаете, что сама фраза вполне нормальная, но надо только переставить слово "поздравил". Не очень понимаю, почему так плохо: я хотел расставить именно таким образом и вроде в русском языке порядок слов довольно свободный и это позволяет.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Дополню сейчас ответ

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас почитаю! Заметил, что в своём комментарии пропустил слово "акценты": *я хотел расставить **акценты** именно таким образом.*

Comment: Возможно, и правда есть двусмысленность, но первого примера я не понял. Мне кажется, что в устной речи при произнесении этого с правильной интонацией всё встаёт на свои места.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой не вижу такой интонации. Ну какой интонаций при таком построении фразы вы объясните, что "поздравил в том числе и (с тем-то и тем-то)" , а не "в том числе и поздравил (с тем же)"?